# Add a FadeOut/FadeIn to a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been creating a site for a school project. I have everything pretty much done except for the slideshow. I have the javascript in and ready and the photos are sliding fine, but I wanted to know if there was a way to make the photos fade in and out and where I should put the "fade" function in the code? I am sure its pretty easy, but can't figure it out

I looked at the other example and I think it ahs something to do with the opacity feature, but not sure where to put it in this project?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "images/jambalaya.png" // set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "images/sucio_rice.png"
</script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var step=0

function slideit(){
 if (!document.images)
  return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
 if (step<1)
  step++
 else
  step=0
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

slideit()

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/home_btn2.png')">

<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <img src="images/crab_logo_edit.png" width="652" height="140" alt="Singing Crab" />
    </h1>
</div>

<div id="content" class="wrap_home">

<h2>Arriba!</h2>

<div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/jambalaya.png" id="slide" width="400" height="330" alt="Marsa Alam" />
</div>

    <p>There's always a fiesta at The Singing Crab—The best Cajun food Louisiana has to offer! Heavy on the spices, The Singing Crab has                                the absolute best that Cajun has to offer.</p>

<h2>You'll love it. We just guarantee.</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

//variable that will increment through the images
var step=0

function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
  return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
 if (step<1)
  step++
 else
  step=0
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

slideit()

</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to prepare jsFiddle of what you have right now? That will make us help you quicker..

Answer (score 0):

Um.. Didn't get why do you have 2 `slideIt()` functions declared, but any way, just rewrite this function to

```
function slideit(){
   if (!document.images) return;
   $('#slide').fadeOut(150,function(){
       $('#slide').attr('src', slideimages[step].src);
       $('#slide').fadeIn(150);
   });
   step = step < 0 ? step++ : 0;
}
var intervalId = setInterval(slideIt, 2500);
```

This is the jQuery solution, much shorter, much more beautiful than pure js. But you can make it with js only and no libs, just add this func to your code

```
function fade( elem, time ){
    var startOpacity = elem.style.opacity || 1;
    elem.style.opacity = startOpacity;

    (function go() {
         elem.style.opacity -= startOpacity / ( time / 100 );
         elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + elem.style.opacity * 100 + ')';

         if( elem.style.opacity > 0 )
            setTimeout( go, 100 );
         else
           elem.style.display = 'none';
     })();
 }
```

And manipulate with it instead of jQuery `fadeIn/fadeOut` functions.
You can pick each, but i advise you jQuery.

Comment: So I put it in there and it sets everything fine, but now it is no longer sliding and it doesn't like the "var intervalId" for some reason, edited the code in original post for visual

Comment: Sry, was my mistake, change the old intervalId to the one is in the code right now.